# Intercept Paste Event on JavaFx HTMLEditor

Tags: java, javafx

Hello I want to know how to intercept the **Paste Event** in the **JavaFX HTMLEditor**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. The HTMLEditor uses a WebPage internally. Basically during a paste event it sends a "paste" command via

```
private boolean executeCommand(String command, String value) {
    return webPage.executeCommand(command, value);
}
```

and then a

```
twkExecuteCommand(getPage(), command, value);
```

However, you could intercept everything that implicitly invokes the paste event like the button click or a CTRL+V key combination and depending on what you wish to do consume the event.

Example:

```
public class HTMLEditorSample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        final HTMLEditor htmlEditor = new HTMLEditor();

        Scene scene = new Scene(htmlEditor, 800, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        Button button = (Button) htmlEditor.lookup(".html-editor-paste");
        button.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> {
            System.out.println("paste pressed");
            // e.consume();
        });

        htmlEditor.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {
            if( e.isControlDown() && e.getCode() == KeyCode.V) {
                System.out.println( "CTRL+V pressed");
                // e.consume();
            }
        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

As to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28783418/paste-only-plain-text-on-java-fx-htmleditor) with pasting only plain text to the html editor, you could do it like this:

```
public class HTMLEditorSample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        final HTMLEditor htmlEditor = new HTMLEditor();

        Scene scene = new Scene(htmlEditor, 800, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        Button button = (Button) htmlEditor.lookup(".html-editor-paste");
        button.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> {
            modifyClipboard();
        });

        htmlEditor.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {
            if( e.isControlDown() && e.getCode() == KeyCode.V) {
                modifyClipboard();
            }
        });

    }

    private void modifyClipboard() {
        Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();

        String plainText = clipboard.getString();
        ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
        content.putString(plainText);

        clipboard.setContent(content);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

It's a workaround and ugly because you should never modify the clipboard content unless the user wants to, but it works. On the other hand, it may be possible to revert the clipboard content back to its original state after the paste operation.

Edit:

Here's how you could access the contextmenu, e. g. for disabling it:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) htmlEditor.lookup(".web-view");
webView.setContextMenuEnabled(false);
```

Comment: This works perfectly for the Paste button on the ToolBar and to action Ctrl + V, but when we call the paste action from the context Menu Popup the method `modifyClipboard ()` is not called. Exist any way to get the action from the context menu paste item?

Comment: I added code about how to get the WebView in order for you to e. g. disable the context menu or add your custom event handler in order to add your own context menu.

Comment: Thanks I used the method `setOnContextMenuRequested()` of the webview and the modifyClipbord (), worked perfectly!

Comment: this is helpfull , i changed it for mouse click listener:
htmlEditor.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> {
            if (e.getTarget().toString().contains("html-editor-paste")) {
                System.out.println("paste pressed");
                // e.consume();
            }
        });

Answer (score 0):

Don't try this line, because it's always return a NULL:

```
 Button button = (Button) htmlEditor.lookup(".html-editor-paste");
```

The only way to get the Paste button from HTMLEditor is the solution from @taha:

```
htmlEditor.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> { if (e.getTarget().toString().contains("html-editor-paste")) { System.out.println("paste pressed"); });
```